# video uploading using PHP

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I am using the following code for uploading videos

```
    $img1 = $_FILES['video']['name'];

    if (!empty($img1)) {

        $fname = $_FILES['video']['name'];

        $img_name1 = "video/" . $fname;

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'], $img_name1)){
            $new_name = ShowFileName($fname);

             $output = 'video/'.$new_name.'.flv';

             $command = "$ffmpegpath  -i $img_name1  -s 486x368 -b 400kb  -ac 1 -ar 44100 -r 25 -s 320x240 -f flv $output";
             $command = $ffmpegpath.' -i'.$img_name1.' -s 486x368 -b 400kb  -ac 1 -ar 44100 -r 25 -qmin 3 -qmax 5 -y '.$output;
             exec($command);

             $thumb_dir = 'video_thumbs/';

             $thumb = $new_name.'jpg';

             exec($ffmpegpath .' -i '.$img_name1.' -an -y -f mjpeg -ss 0.05 -vframes 1 '.$thumb_dir.$img_name1);
             unlink($img_name1);
        }
     }
```

It is working properly.ie Successfully moving video into videos folder and insering video name to database table. But the problem is related to the thumb image of this video. Thumb name was insert into database but the image wasn't uploding to the video_thumb folder.......
please help me....

Comment: This has nothing to do with php5 or file uploads. The problem is with your ffmpeg call that is supposed to make the thumbnail. It is not making it for some reason. I don't know enough about ffmpeg to know what that problem is. But it definitely seems like some ffmpeg problem.

Comment: Have you tried to execute the image creating ffmpeg command first? If it won't work, then you might have an error, which you can capture, by specifying a second or third argument to the exec call. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I see is with the file name in the ffmpeg command line. If it contains special chars you should use `escapeshellarg()`.
[php function escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)